# Restlet using custom media type

Tags: java, json, restlet, restlet-2.0, media-type

In Restlet 2.3 (SE) I am trying to use media types to control versions. My current attempt involves registering new extensions in my inbound route:

```
@Override
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {

        ...
        getTunnelService().setExtensionsTunnel(true);

        getMetadataService().addExtension("vnd.myapp.v1", MediaType.valueOf("application/vnd.myapp.v1+json"));
        getMetadataService().addExtension("vnd.myapp.v2", MediaType.valueOf("application/vnd.myapp.v2+json"));

        ...
}
```

My resource interface is then setup as follows:

```
public interface UsersResource {

    @Options
    void getCorsSupport();

    @Get("vnd.myapp.v1")
    Collection<User> representV1() throws Exception;

    // Should be the default if */* is specified
    @Get("json | vnd.myapp.v2")
    Collection<User> representV2() throws Exception;

}
```

I then tried specifying the media types as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/users?media=vnd.myapp.v1
```

The idea is that if somebody specifies the media type as `vnd.myapp.v1` they get `representV1()` (JSON), if they specify the media type as `vnd.myapp.v2` they get `representV2()` (JSON) and (optionally) if they ask for nothing specific they get `representV2()`. With the above setup no matter what is requested I always get back `representV2()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I had when testing:

- `Accept: application/vnd.myapp.v1+json` -> `representV1` is called
- `Accept: application/vnd.myapp.v2+json` -> `representV2` is called
- `Accept: application/application/json` -> `representV1` is called
- `Accept: */*` -> `representV1` is called

It seems that the expression `json | vnd.myapp.v2` doesn't work properly. The workaround is to split representV2 into two methods with `json` and `vnd.myapp.v2`.

When no accept header is specified, it seems that Restlet calls the first method with annotation `Get` it finds.

Something that could help you is to enable traces to see the scores of the different methods:

```
public class RestletLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Engine.getInstance().setLogLevel(Level.FINEST);
        launchApplication();
    }
}
```

You'll see traces like that:

```
Score of annotation "MethodAnnotationInfo [javaMethod: public org.restlet.representation.Representation test.MyServerResource1.testGetVnd1(), javaClass: class test.MyServerResource1, restletMethod: GET, input: vnd.myapp.v1, value: vnd.myapp.v1, output: vnd.myapp.v1, query: null]"= 0.5
Total score of variant "[application/vnd.myapp.v1+json]"= 0.04191667
Score of annotation "MethodAnnotationInfo [javaMethod: public org.restlet.representation.Representation test.MyServerResource1.testGetJson(), javaClass: class test.MyServerResource1, restletMethod: GET, input: json, value: json, output: json, query: null]"= 0.5
Total score of variant "[application/json]"= 0.04191667
Score of annotation "MethodAnnotationInfo [javaMethod: public org.restlet.representation.Representation test.MyServerResource1.testGetVnd2(), javaClass: class test.MyServerResource1, restletMethod: GET, input: vnd.myapp.v2, value: vnd.myapp.v2, output: vnd.myapp.v2, query: null]"= 0.5
Total score of variant "[application/vnd.myapp.v2+json]"= 0.04191667
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 1):

It gets better when removing the spaces character in the annotation such as:

```
@Get("json|vnd.myapp.v2")
```

I've entered an issue to fix this. https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/1099

best regards, Thierry Boileau

Comment: issue fixed. the fix will be available in 2.3.3.